# No module found torch

Tags: pytorch, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-deepstream

I am using jetson NX xavier kit having cuda 10.2.89, open Cv 4.1.1 and tensorRT 7.1.3 . Trying to install pytorch. Tried installing with this line

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

but when i write this line

```
import torch
```

It throws an error by saying that module not installed.

How I can verify if pytorch has been installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch
```

After executing this command, you need to enter yes(if prompted in the command line) for installing all the related packages. If there is no conflict while installing the libraries, the PyTorch library will be installed.
To check if it is properly installed or not, type the command `python` in your command line and type `import torch` to check if it is properly installed or not.